# In Perl how do you dynamically pick what method to use as a callback?

Tags: perl, callback, reference, package

In Perl, it's pretty trivial to specify a callback or code reference if its package is known:

```
package Foo;

sub foo { print "in foo" }

# and then
package main;

sub baz {
    my $code = shift;
    $code->();
}

baz( \&Foo::foo );
```

And this prints `in foo`.

Lets say you have an object, ever so trivial, like this:

```
package Foo;

sub new { bless {}, shift }
sub bar { print "in bar" }
sub baz { print "in baz" }
```

You can look up the method using the above way (\&Package:Method) and call it like

```
package main;
my $foo = Foo->new();
my $ref = \&Foo::bar;
$foo->$ref();
```

But sometimes (okay, often) you don't know the explicit type.  Lets say there's `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`, and they all have their own `blat` method.  You'd want to get the reference to the appropriate method, based on the object instead of the package.  How would you go about that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my $ref = $obj->can('blat');
```

If $ref is undef, your object can't blat.  If $ref is not undef, it's a valid CODE reference to the function in question, suitable for calling "$obj->$ref(@args)".

Answer (score 4):

Let method lookup do the work for you:

```
$ cat try
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

package Foo;
sub new { bless {} => shift }
sub blat { "Foo blat" }

package Bar;
sub new { bless {} => shift }
sub blat { "Bar blat" }

package Baz;
sub new { bless {} => shift }
sub blat { "Baz blat" }

package main;

my $method = "blat";
foreach my $obj (Foo->new, Bar->new, Baz->new) {
  print $obj->$method, "\n";
}

$ ./try
Foo blat
Bar blat
Baz blat
```

If you need a reference, keep in mind that Perl doesn't have delegates, but you can get close:

```
my @objs = (Foo->new, Bar->new, Baz->new);

my $method = "blat";
my $obj = $objs[rand @objs];
my $ref = $obj->can($method);

if ($ref) {
  print $ref->($obj), "\n";
}
else {
  print "$obj: no can $method\n";
}
```

Even closer would be:

```
my $delegate = sub { $obj->$ref };
#           or sub { $obj->$method }
print $delegate->(), "\n";
```

Comment: can is defiantly the right way to go - but the UNIVERSAL perldoc page explicitly says DO NOT do UNIVERSAL::can() directly - this makes it so overrides don't work.  

see http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html